# How to drag SCNNode along specific axis after rotation?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am currently working on Swift ARKit project.

I am trying to figure out how can I drag node object at specific axis even after some rotations. For example I want to move node along Y axis after rotations but It's axis directions stays same so even if I change Y position it's still move along World Y. SCNNode.localup is static and returns SCNVector3(0, 1, 0) and as far as I see there is no function for node's local up. If I remember correctly, it was enough to increase the local axis to drag after rotating in Unity.

[Node object before rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jROjt.jpg)

Before applying some rotations to drag object all you need to do is increasing or decreasing specific axis.

[Node object after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Webf7.jpg)

After rotate green Y axis rotates too but when I increase or decrease local Y value object still moves along World Y.

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, how are you currently applying the rotation?

A straightforward way to achieve this without needing to dig into quaternion math would be to wrap your node in question inside a parent node, and apply those transformations separately. You can apply the rotation to the parent node, and then the drag motion along the axis to the child node.

If introducing this layer would be problematic outside of this operation, you can add/rotate/translate/remove as a single atomic operation, using `node.convertPosition(_:to:)` to interchange between local and world coordinates after you've applied all the transformations.

```
let parent = SCNNode()
rootNode.addChildNode(parent)
parent.simdPosition = node.simdPosition
node.simdPosition = .zero

parent.simdRotation = /../
node.simdPosition = simd_float3(0, localYAxisShift, 0) 
node.simdPosition = rootNode.convertPosition(node.simdPosition, from: parent)
rootNode.addChildNode(node)
rootNode.removeChildNode(parent)
```

I didn't test the above code, but the general approach should work. In general, compound motion as you describe is a bit more complex to do directly on the node itself, and under the hood SceneKit is doing all of that for you when using the above approach.

---

### Edit

Here's a version that just does the matrix transform directly rather than relying on the built in accommodations.

```
let currentTransform = node.transform
let yShift = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, localYAxisShift, 0)
node.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(yShift, currentTransform)
```

This should shift your object along the 'local' y axis. Note that matrix multiplication is non-commutative, i.e. the order of parameters in the `SCNMatrix4Mult` call is important (try reversing them to illustrate).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 

Currently I am sending ray to denormalized position of click position and creating anchor with hit result.worldTransform. After that I am placing node object with this anchor so It's kinda comes with rotation. I will try your solution but I wish there is something like localup for each node in Scene.

Comment: Well, yeah that's not exactly what `localup` is meant to be in the context of SceneKit and many other rendering engines, but I went ahead and edited the answer to include the direct approach of modifying the matrix to achieve your desired outcome. Perhaps this is more aligned with what you're looking for!